# Unable to run Android - DeviceReady in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am unable to run android's device ready function (not getting fired). How do I fix it? I have target sdk 22 and cordova 5.1.1 and android studio 1.0.1.

My index.html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Device Ready Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
 function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);
}

// Handle the batterystatus event
//
function onBatteryStatus(info) {
    console.log("Level: " + info.level + " isPlugged: " + info.isPlugged);
}
```

And where will this get logged :  console.log("Level: " + info.level + " isPlugged: " + info.isPlugged);

If I run on command propmpt: cordova build:

Total time: 7.545 secs

```
 C:\Users\salangar\hello\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
 Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c  "C:\Users\salangar\hello\platform
s\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b           C:\Users\salangar\hello\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
 ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
   at ChildProcess.whenDone    (C:\Users\salangar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
   at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Logcat display:

```
I/WebViewFactory﹕ Loading com.android.webview version 39 (1737576-arm) (code 300001)  
07-02 11:10:44.806    HelloWorld I/LibraryLoader﹕ Time to load native libraries: 726 ms (timestamps 7130-7856)
07-02 11:10:44.824    HelloWorld I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
07-02 11:10:44.979    HelloWorld V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider﹕ Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {951e68}
07-02 11:10:44.990    HelloWorld I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
  07-02 11:10:45.113    HelloWorld I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
  07-02 11:10:45.021    HelloWorld I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(104)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
    07-02 11:10:45.140    HelloWorld W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
07-02 11:10:45.448    HelloWorld W/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ Requires BLUETOOTH permission
07-02 11:10:45.575    HelloWorld W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()
07-02 11:10:45.590    HelloWorld I/chromium﹕ [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(65)] Load from apk succesful, fd=31 off=46184 len=3037
07-02 11:10:45.614    HelloWorld I/chromium﹕ [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:32 off:229484 len:1089587
07-02 11:10:45.828    HelloWorld E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(165)] No suitable EGL configs found.
07-02 11:10:45.829    HelloWorld E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
07-02 11:10:45.835    HelloWorld E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(988)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff failed
07-02 11:10:46.790    HelloWorld W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(331)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
07-02 11:10:47.032    HelloWorld W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
07-02 11:10:47.115    HelloWorld W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
07-02 11:10:47.328    HelloWorld D/SystemWebViewEngine﹕ CordovaWebView is running on device made by: unknown
07-02 11:10:47.408    HelloWorld W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
07-02 11:10:47.408    HelloWorld W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
07-02 11:10:47.712    HelloWorld I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3517(255KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 31% free, 764KB/1117KB, paused 2.313ms total 499.804ms
07-02 11:10:48.445    HelloWorld D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-02 11:10:55.758    HelloWorld D/JsMessageQueue﹕ Set native->JS mode to OnlineEventsBridgeMode
07-02 11:10:56.152    HelloWorld I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3730(208KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 53% free, 887KB/1911KB, paused 1.825ms total 326.232ms
07-02 11:10:57.749    HelloWorld I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 11:11:00.752    HelloWorld I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 11:11:01.075    HelloWorld I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 11:11:01.545    HelloWorld I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1188)] "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1188)
07-02 11:11:01.750    HelloWorld I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1181)] "Channel not fired: onPluginsReady", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1181)
 07-02 11:11:01.752    HelloWorld I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1181)] "Channel not fired: onCordovaReady", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1181)
  07-02 11:11:03.655    HelloWorld W/PluginManager﹕ THREAD WARNING: exec() call to CoreAndroid.show blocked the main thread for 161ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
07-02 11:11:04.699    HelloWorld I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(47)] "Received Event: deviceready", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (47)
 07-02 11:11:27.708    HelloWorld I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 07-02 11:11:28.112    HelloWorld I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 11:11:58.646    HelloWorld I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: You should update your Android Studio since the latest version is 1.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. device ready function (not getting fired). How do I fix it?

You don't need to use onLoad() function to call deviceready event. 
instead of this :-

```
function onLoad() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

just write :- 
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

and another thing is you need to write the script cordova.js part inside the body tag and add the index.js file like the cordova.js.

2. where will this get logged : console.log("Level: " + info.level + " isPlugged: " + info.isPlugged);

This log is print in logcat.

Hope this help :) if you have any difficulties please let me know.

Comment: Thanks. But, this did not resolve my issue and if I try to run it via command prompt, I get :  BUILD FAILED. edited question.

Comment: You want to build your app using android studio or not?

Comment: Ok then just open your studio and import project. its ask you for path of the project then just point  your project location\platforms\android. After import you can build your app using android studio. If you have any problem then I am here to help you. :)

Comment: I have already done that! My emulator doesn't show up anything except "connecting to device" and nothing on the logcat

Comment: Did You create some page or something else which you want to show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82157/discussion-between-biswajit-and-smitha).